# Heavy PNG from CSS sprite online generator, why?

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

I used a couple of CSS sprite online generators (e.g., Stitches, Instant Sprite, SpritePad) and, even though they work well (I by far prefer SpritePad), the output PNG is always four to five times heavier than all my images together (58 images). I wonder why this happens.

For instance, my images together weights 1.2 MB, and the lighter image coming from the online generator (in this case, SpritePad) weights 4.9 MB. I thought it was because the blank spaces in between, but with SpritePad I nicely arranged my images to avoid too much blank spaces.

So, before editing my website with DIVs and other CSS stuff, I would appreciate some tips to get an output image of a similar size of all my images together (i.e., 1.2 MB) with CSS sprite. My website is actually 1.2 MB (my code is minified and really tiny) and it takes about 28 seconds to load, imagine if I use a 5 MB image, it would take 2 min to load? that's nuts (I have just 300-400 kB upload bandwidth and so far have no ways to get more).

Any hints are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: You can always use PNG compressors like [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) (online) or [RIOT](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/) (desktop), they're pretty good.

Comment: @Tyblitz thanks, I indeed used these tools to reduce the size of my 58 images, I imagine that a further compression of my CSS sprite PNG image would affect quality, would that happen? I will give it a shot.